# Call for Photography Gear Grant applicants: May 2012 (Updated)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, gear-grant-program

**Update: Grantees for May have been chosen and notified via email. Please check back at the end of the month for a new meta question opening up applications for the June round.**

---

After a [trial run](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/call-for-participants-in-photography-gear-lending-library) and [first full-fledged round](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2135/call-for-photography-gear-grant-applicants-april-2012) of this program, I wanted to get started on the next round. My goal is to select a new group of 3-6 people every month.

The purpose of this program is to generate content about photography gear that is either very common or very new and exciting - basically, to help ensure that if people are searching for answers to their questions about photographic gear, that Photography Stack Exchange shows up with relevant information. We want to make it easier for people to find answers to the questions they are interested in.

**I'm currently looking for participants in this photography gear rental reimbursement program who want to rent equipment in the month of May.**

<sub>If you are interested in this program but don't think you have time in May to rent, experiment with, and write about the equipment you have in mind, please wait until a future round. I'll put up a new meta post at the end of May or beginning of June asking for applicants for the June round.</sub>

**The basics:**

- For each round, I am looking for 3-6 users. The total number of participants will depend upon interest and the equipment people request. In the event that we have far more applicants than spots, participants new to this program will take precedence over those who have already received a grant. You can, however, apply to this program every month as long as you fulfill your site activity requirements for each round you are selected for.
- General budget per person is a maximum of $400 (USD: rental + shipping, if necessary.)
- You're responsible for adhering to the terms and conditions of the standard rental agreement of whatever retailer you choose to rent from.
- This program is open to all users who have a reputation score of 300 and above. There are no geographic limitations other than residing in a country that PayPal serves; as long as you agree to everything listed below and have access to either a physical store or an online retailer local to you, you can enter.

**The details:**

- Each user selected will rent equipment using his or her own credit card and shipping address. All equipment rentals must be pre-approved by Stack Exchange (via the form you use to enter into this program and the email you will receive from Stack Exchange confirming your participation if you are selected).
- Each user will choose a product(s) from a physical store or online retailer of his or her choice, for a period up to three weeks, budget permitting. Stack Exchange will cover the cost of the rental, any applicable taxes, and the cost of shipping between you and the retailer (if you are renting online). We will not cover any additional insurance purchased, any damage fees or late return fees. **It is your responsibility to familiarize yourself with and abide by the terms and conditions of the company you rent from.**
- Every rental will require a minimum amount of activity in exchange for reimbursement of rental costs. ***This will vary depending on the complexity of the gear and duration of the rental***; for example, renting a Nikon D3 kit for a week will require a greater amount of site participation (questions asked or blog posts written) than renting a ring flash for two days will. The minimum will be asking three questions or writing one blog post, but I reserve the right to adjust these amounts. Either way, if you are selected for participation, you'll receive an email from me telling you what your minimum site requirements will be.
- Reimbursement will be done by PayPal; you must scan and email your rental receipts to me (laura@stackexchange.com), and you will be reimbursed after the return of the rental equipment and after you have completed posting your questions and/or blog articles. **Please include links to your questions and/or blog posts when you send me your receipt.**(You'll need to contact [rfusca](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1917/rfusca) or [jrista](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/124/jrista) for access to the [Photo.SE blog](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/).)

**To sign up:**

- Fill out [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDc1QU5oajVzeHJadUNNeWVsVk9qQVE6MQ). (And make sure your email address is accurate!)
- All users who are selected to participate in this beta round will be contacted via email by Tuesday, May 1, 2012. I'll update this post to let everyone know that the users have been selected.

This is still a new and fairly complex program. Please be patient as we work out any kinks that may appear, and don't hesitate to submit your feedback at any point in the process.