# What resources is Stack Exchange dedicating to meeting the needs of Photography Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, advertisements

It's been more than six months since [this post](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6913/were-testing-advertisements-on-photography) promising

> Generating revenue from non-technology sites will enable us to dedicate more resources to meeting your needs so this is **good news**.

(Emphasis original)

... and thirteen weeks since the last update from anyone on Stack Exchange staff to [What can Stack Exchange do to better build a photography community of practice here?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/what-can-stack-exchange-do-to-better-build-a-photography-community-of-practice-h), which was my attempt to be practical and positive rather than cynical.

On that last post in September, a Stack Exchange staff member said "Updates to come soon." Can we at least have a little update, please? I'm swinging back around to cynical on this.

And see  [Photography Gear Lending Library - brainstorming](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/photography-gear-lending-library-brainstorming), from 2012. I'm not calling for the reinstatement of that particular program, but it was exactly the kind of experimentation and involvement I hoped that this meant. And there was that time all high-rep users got a shipment of swag (stickers, a Photo-SE logo t-shirt, and a custom Photo-SE microfiber cloth!) — not necessary, but definitely made me feel appreciated. I was genuinely hoping this meant a return to that level of attention or even better, where it felt like a collaborative partnership between community building questions and answers and company providing support and enablement.

*Or is it all just platitudes to make us feel better about our free sharing of knowledge being monetized while company neglect continues?*

---

Note: in order to increase the chances of getting some kind of attention, I have [cross-posted this to the main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340383/154627).

Comment: Please [see the answer that I posted on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340515/51) to address this question.